# MySQL - remove non numeric and non commas from string

Tags: mysql

There are tons of answers how to remove non numeric characters:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('áőüóöúeád1.23asd12,333-%!', '[^0-9]', '');
```

but I also need to keep the commas so the result would be:

```
12312,333
```

how to do that?

Comment: Just include the comma in the regex?? `'[^0-9,]'`

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE('áőüóöúeád1.23asd12,333-%!', '[^0-9]+,', ''); so?

Comment: What? No? I gave you the answer in the comment itself. Did you read it?

Comment: Please make an answer so I can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the comma in the regex. `'[^0-9,]'`